# How can I can create a world that a player can easily get lost in?

Tags: unity, game-design, path-finding, unityscript

I am a 3D environmental artist and I'm currently planning an independent passion game project of mine. I have the concept of crazy hallways that lead to the rooms that the player has already visited, infinite staircases (similar to super mario 64), basically i want the player to be able to get lost in my world very easily. Does anybody have any tips on how i can make this possible? 
I am developing my game in Unity3D.
Thanks,
Mitch

Comment: When you are looking for inspiration, you might want to check out [Antichamber](http://www.antichamber-game.com/). It's also made in Unity, by the way.

Comment: I would go for triangulation. Plop down n rooms and connect them through triangulation. This way you create many loops in your maze.

Comment: Wow, antichamber is pretty darn trippy. Impressive that its built in unity. Does anybody know how any of these trippy elements are made?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by teleporting the player around - in the case of a staircase, after reaching a certain point just reposition the player several steps back. Of course, the environment would have to be crafted in a way so that the player doesn't notice it (that is, when he looks around in both locations (place where the teleport is and the place he gets teleported to) they need to look the same). You can help this effect by reducing visibility / adding fog and whatnot. 
For the rooms, you can try making each room a separate building block and make it so that when the player opens a door (or gets near them), you move the appropriate room on the other side. In this case it would be easier if you don't allow the player to have multiple doors open at the same time.
Basically you want to create some kind of a trigger platform, and when the player collides with it you move either him or the rooms around.

Comment: This is a really good idea, subtly teleporting the player to different locations would be pretty crazy. Thanks!